# Is there a scope equivalent RequestScope for JMS

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jms

Similar to `@RequestScope` is there something equivalent for a given JMS Message? Ideally you could specify for a given `@JmsListener` destination, beans which would be created and autowired, is this possible?

Comment: Not out-of-the-box. What is your more precise usecase?

Comment: Our application has different regions, and I want to have different service implementations based on the region, which is an attribute in the JMS message.

Comment: Launch different versions of your application and make the services implement the same interface and make the actual dependency conditional on a property and use a JMS Filter to select the proper messages. Or have a method on your service to determine if it can handle the message and select the proper one upon execution (just itertate over a list of services).

Comment: Don't really want to launch whole new entire different versions of my application, that's a massive sledge hammer approach. Was looking for a nice Spring-way of doing it with bean scopes, not clustery if statements through my code base.

Comment: Equivalent to RequestScope, but for JMS, not interested in anything else, thanks.

Comment: No there isn't and trying to implement it would make things only more complex imho.

Answer (score 2):

The sender would need to add the region identifier as a message property, like `message.setStringProperty("region", "SW");`

You will then be able to set up different beans for each region, like
`@JmsListener(destination = "mydestination", selector = "region='SW'")`

Comment: This is a good idea too, but it would still require me to put the region in other places other than region specific services. I also don’t want to instantiate region services not needed , and there maybe more than one region active at anytime